# awk commands in file gives error when executed in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

**file_data.txt**

`73|8|42.320000|1559260800000|1|9667|0.00|42.320000||1485613678440|
153|8|35.680000|1559260800000|1|10899|0.00|35.680000||1482480306523|
2503|8|93.390000|1559260800000|1|6106|0.00|93.390000||1484304241803|
2672|8|49.990000|1559260800000|1|7754|0.00|49.990000||1482064270543|`

**AWK_COMMANDS.txt**

```
awk -F '|' '$2 == 3280 {print;}' file_data.txt
awk -F '|' '$2 == 3281 {print;}' file_data.txt
```

I am running below while loop

```
while read line
do
 $line
done < AWK_COMMANDS.txt
```

I am getting below error

`awk: cmd. line:1: '$2
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: '$2
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression`

when I execute the same command in console directly it works.

I tried escaping & double quotes. It results same

Comment: This is a no no. The `' '` are literal after the expansion, not syntactical.

Comment: Why not just run `bash AWK_COMMANDS.txt`

Comment: `bash AWK_COMMANDS.txt` works.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 is good read about (not) putting commands in variables.

Comment: @Ashish, Could you please do lemme know if my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with plain bash, you would write

```
while IFS='|' read -r first second rest; do
    case $second in
        3280|3281) echo "$first|$second|$rest" ;;
    esac
done < file_data.txt
```

But stick with awk: it's more concise, equally readable, and MUCH faster.